# Will a periodic (Every Monday) job on slave be able to run in Jenkins while the master is offline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, master-slave

I have a linux slave and windows master configured in Jenkins. However if i am scheduling periodic job on the linux slave and i shutdown my master (Windows), will the scheduled job execute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in case of Jenkins is definitive no, but here is what you have as an alternative https://www.rundeck.com is the modern it operations management platform in other words it is scheduller with UI wich can a lot of power and if just need to run simple cases one per week it will do that job.

Ofc, you can always use cron with some shell scripts we it is an *nix system

Answer (score 0):

No! You cannot.

All the jobs will be configured on Master and Master tells slaves to do what and when. So, its quite obvious that you cannot have what you are asking.